# php array, error when filtering array and the value is not present

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use `isset` to check if the `$filtered_data` returns a set of data.

I'm using this code rather than `foreach` because datasetID is a unique id.

My novice understanding is that `if (isset($filtered_data))` returns true or false? So the `if` mrans that if records are returned do `x`. So, currently when I put in `$lastPart = '5fd4058e5c8d2'` I'm getting the expected result. When I change the 2 to a 3 (a non-existing ID)  `$lastPart = '5fd4058e5c8d3'` I get Undefined index: 5fd4058e5c8d3`.

I expect the `isset` is doing its job and the error is thrown on this line as indicated in the error message `$filtered_data = array_column(array_merge(...$data), null, 'datasetID')[$lastPart];` am I missing the obvious? I guess this needs a get out clause if the value `$lastPart` does not exist in the array?

```
$filtered_data = array_column(array_merge(...$data), null, 'datasetID')[$lastPart];

if (isset($filtered_data)){
  echo 'qwertyuio';
  $datasetID = $filtered_data['datasetID'];
  $collectionCode = $filtered_data['collectionCode'];
  $datasetName = $filtered_data['datasetName'];
  $ownerInstitutionCode = $filtered_data['ownerInstitutionCode'];
  $vernacularName = $filtered_data['vernacularName'];
  $elementName = strtolower($filtered_data['elementName']);
} else {
  echo 'not set';
}
```

Comment: `array_column()` always returns an array, so `$filtered_data` will always be set.

Comment: @Barmar True, but the OP is attempting to assign an element in that returned array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to use null coalescing (`??`) and setting the value to a dummy value if not found, then your `isset()` can be reworked to check for the dummy value...

```
$filtered_data = array_column(array_merge(...$data), null, 'datasetID')[$lastPart] 
                  ?? null;

if ($filtered_data){
```

Comment: great, that works! But you say `quick fix` is it the best fix, the best way to do this?

Comment: TBH, without knowing how the data is created, it is a simple fix.  IF you could alter the `$data` array, you could index it by the  `'datasetID'` column as you load it, then use `isset($data[$lastPart])`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the obvious: you're trying to access a non-existent element when you assign it to `$filtered_data`, so the error occurs there. You're not testing for its existence until the next line.

Try this:

```
$filtered_data = array_column(array_merge(...$data), null, 'datasetID');
if (isset($filtered_data[$lastPart]) {
  $filtered_data = $filtered_data[$lastPart];
  echo 'qwertyuio';
  $datasetID = $filtered_data['datasetID'];
  $collectionCode = $filtered_data['collectionCode'];
  $datasetName = $filtered_data['datasetName'];
  $ownerInstitutionCode = $filtered_data['ownerInstitutionCode'];
  $vernacularName = $filtered_data['vernacularName'];
  $elementName = strtolower($filtered_data['elementName']);
} else {
  echo 'not set';
}
```